# Complex polarizability of a dielectric sphere in a homohenious electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, polarization, classical-electrodynamics, dielectric

It is well known that complex polarizability of uniform dielectric sphere with radius $r$ and complex permittivity $\hat\epsilon_{in}(\omega)$ placed in a medium with complex permittivity $\hat\epsilon_{out}(\omega)$ under homogeneous electric field with circular frequency $\omega$ is defined by (in the [CGS system of units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGS)):

$$\hat\alpha(\omega)=r^3 {\hat\epsilon_{in}(\omega)-\hat\epsilon_{out}(\omega)\over \hat\epsilon_{in}(\omega)+2\hat\epsilon_{out}(\omega)}$$

This relation is derived for the static case in many textbooks on electrostatics (see [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DielectricSphereInAUniformElectricField/) related demonstration). What about the dynamic case?

Comment: What do you mean by "static case" ? The quantities dependent on $\omega$ describe response of the medium to oscillating harmonic field.

Comment: @Ján The static case is the case of static field, in this case the equation of course should be written without $\omega$. This case is considered in many textbooks and places, for example [here](http://www.problemsinelectrodynamics.com/dielectrics/a-dielectric-sphere-in-a-homogeneous-electric-field#show-solution).

Comment: Mie scattering deals with high-frequency fields in the vicinity of dielectric sphere: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering (just in case you did not came across it yet).

Comment: @Ján I consider the case when no scattering occurs.